# Notation to represent the columns of a matrix

Tags: matrices, notation

I have a matrix $\mathbf{Q}$ and would like to represent the $j^{th}$ column-vector of this matrix. Is there a standard mathematical-notation to do that? I have seen things like $Q_{*j}$, but I am not sure if it is a standard notation.

Comment: I've seen $q^j$ in this case ($q_i$ for rows); eg, Artin, Algebra (from memory).

Comment: Ah, interesting. I'm surprised that there is no formalized notation for this. It looks like people pick their own convention?

Comment: I don't know. :) Maybe there is an almost standard notation. This is what I'm using - it strikes me as fairly intuitive.

Comment: Yes, it makes sense to me as well. Thank you!

Comment: Depending on the context, I've seen people occasionally use MATLAB notation, $Q(: , j)$.

Comment: It depends. If you need to introduce a notation only for columns, it is not hard just to say that $q_i$ denotes the $i$th column of $Q$. If you need to denote both rows and columns, the MATLAB notation $Q(:,i)$ or its analogs (IMHO more neat) $Q_{*,i}$ or $Q_{:,i}$ is perfectly valid. Note that using upper index notation may complicate notation, e.g., for transposing (you should use parentheses then to denote $(q^i)^T$).